# Database entry cfqueryparam dynamic session variable value

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

How do you create a cfqueryparam for a dynamic variable? How do I write the value for something like this..

Dynamic Session Variables:

```
<cfset session.checkout.info["firstname_#Add#"]=form["firstname_#Add#"]>
<cfset session.checkout.info["middlename_#Add#"]=form["middlename_#Add#"]>
<cfset session.checkout.info["lastname_#Add#"]=form["lastname_#Add#"]>
```

Database Entry:

```
<cfquery datasource="Titlesbymail" name="InsertEntry">
INSERT INTO owner (firstname, middlename, lastname)
VALUES (<cfqueryparam value="#session.checkout.info.firstname#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR"> 
        <cfqueryparam value="#session.checkout.info.middlename#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">, 
        <cfqueryparam value="#session.checkout.info.lastname#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">
</cfquery>
```

Comment: The syntax is no different just because you are using `cfqueryparam`. You just have to watch out for the quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you just do it like this :

```
<cfloop index="Add" from="1" to="#session.checkout.quantity.pcount#" step="1">
   <cfif structKeyExists(session, "checkout")>
      <cfquery datasource="Titlesbymail" name="InsertEntry">
         INSERT INTO owner (firstname, middlename, lastname)
         VALUES (
            <cfqueryparam value='#form["firstname_#Add#"]#' cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' />
           , <cfqueryparam value='#form["middlename_#Add#"]#' cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' />
           , <cfqueryparam value='#form["lastname_#Add#"]#' cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar'  />
      </cfquery>
  </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: How would you create the database in this case? Lets say there are 3  firstnames the cfqueryparam would just submit all three firstnames in the first name column? How would you do that if you wanted to show that all three of those names entered were for the same transaction? @Leigh